# How do you lift a question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

Now, I know this question has been answered a load of times but please read my question before downvoting it.

I was question banned in June due to bad question (4 closures, 2 duplicates and -8 in votes), at that time, I had 150 reputation points, so I fixed what could be fixable of my questions and I answered a lot of questions and most of my answers got upvoted or chosen as the correct answer. I'm currently at 915 reputation points, yet my question ban is not yet lifted.

According to the topic which I am redirected to as soon as I see the question ban message, it says I should answer a *few* questions that get upvoted and I might get the ban lifted but I'm pretty sure I've answered at least 20 questions which most of got upvoted or chosen as the correct question.

> [image]

Above is my rep per day graph and it's not that bad really.

So if anyone could help me in what I could do more to lift the question ban or give me any specifics that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lets just say I gave you a helping hand and you are out of the ban. **However** - you are still very close to the boundary - I suggest you be very careful of what questions you ask from now on and make sure they are of high quality.

Comment: @Oded Thank you! I couldn't be more thankful, I'll make sure my questions are of high quality and I apologize for the previous bad quality questions, thanks again.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I think that this is a "I've done everything that link asks for but nothing helped. Help?", rather than a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were not far from getting out of the ban - a few more upvotes on some of those questions would have done it.

I have given you a helping hand there, but you are not out of the woods yet - you need to make sure that your future questions are good ones - you are very close to the edge there and getting back into the ban is very easy.

Comment: Maybe you should make that **very close to the edge**

Comment: @rene - I believe the OP is aware of that - no need to stress it.

Comment: Or **very roundabout**.  Or **very siberian khatru**